# Is it possible to insert svg image in ms word 2016 by office js

Tags: javascript, office-js

Ms Word 2016 support insert svg image from GUI but I wonder that is it possible to insert by using office-js? If it is then how? I try to use insert by using context.document.setSelectedDataAsync and pass the base64 svg image but still not worked.

Comment: Are you using an error callback as shown near the bottom of this topic? https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/document.setselecteddataasync If so, what error do you get? How are you converting the SVG to base 64? If you use the exact same code, but a jpeg image instead of svg, does it work?

Comment: The status result is succeed, no error, I converted svg like the way converting the normal image. The normal image is display well but svg is not. After insert document screenshot like this picture: [Error](http://pasteboard.co/vnvyz3fts.png)

Comment: I can reproduce. I will check with the Office development team and report back here. I though we supported SVG, but maybe not.

Comment: Thumbup: did you come to Build 2017 in seattle?

Answer (score 2):

This is currently not supported in the API, but its something we are considering to add in the future. No concrete dates. thanks!